# How to bind html code in the aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have insert html table in the table column (i.e in the form of `<html><table>...</table></html>`). this code return by the parameter from the procedure. I want to show this html in aspx. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can write server side code between `<% %>`

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <% you can put server side here %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this as the `Text` property of a `Literal` control.  See the "Remarks" section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.text.aspx) for information on HTML decoding of the assigned text.

Be aware that this is a possible avenue for a XSS attack, so you'll *really* want to pay attention to concepts of HTML encoding and decoding.